# How to close only one tab (1st) not browser using batch?

Tags: batch

Who to close only one tab not browser using [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) file?

I have researched for a few days and able to run a bat file that opens  multiple websites in 60 sec intervals but I don't want all 30 tabs open.

I'm trying to run in batch file that opens a tab 60 secs later opens another tab and closing the first tab.

What I tried was:

```bat
@echo off 

Title Default Search Browser 
Mode con cols=100 lines=25 & color 2B 

echo & echo WEBSITE=1
Start "" "google.com/search?q=crypto+play+to+earn" 

::  Sleep for 60 seconds, you can change the SleepTime variable
set SleepTime=60
Timeout /T %SleepTime% /NoBreak >NUL 

echo & echo WEBSITE=2
Start "" "google.com/search?q=crypto" 

::  Sleep for 60 seconds, you can change the SleepTime variable
set SleepTime=60 
Timeout /T %SleepTime% /NoBreak >NUL
```

Comment: In any browser? Or in a specific one? Which one?